# Leaked Intent receiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

Here is my code to send text message. I have called the method unregisterReceiver(receiver), But still I'm getting this error in logcat.

```
Intent Receiver leaked that was originally register here. Are you missing to call 
unregisterReciever() ?
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void sendSMS(final Context context, final String phoneNumber, final String message) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    // ---when the SMS has been sent---
     context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("address", phoneNumber);// txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
                values.put("body", message);
                context.getContentResolver().insert(sentURI, values);
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
    context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS not delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }


    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

Note that sms gets sent and delivered and also I'm getting same error on the broadcast receiver for the delivery report.

Comment: call `unregisterReciever();` in `onPause();`

Answer (score 5):

You're registering each time a new anonymous instance of `BroadcastReceiver` and then un-registering a new instance of `BroadcastReceiver` but that will be a different reference from the one you registered.

You need to make this anonymous variable a class variable and then call register/unregister on that reference.

Also make sure you're registering/unregistering in complementary methods:

```
onCreate() / onDestroy()
onResume() / onPause()
```

Comment: `onDestroy()` not guaranty that called always,

Comment: If `onDestroy` is not called when the activity is in the process of being destroyed (because of a crash), then it means the whole application is killed so concerning at that point if the receiver should be unregistered is that least of your concerns since you need to fix the crash anyway.

Answer (score 1):

register like:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        context.unregisterReceiver(this);
        switch (getResultCode()) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("address", phoneNumber);// txtPhoneNo.getText().toString());
            values.put("body", message);
            context.getContentResolver().insert(sentURI, values);
            Toast.makeText(context, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            Toast.makeText(context, "No service",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

in onResume:

```
context.registerReceiver(receiver,new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

and in onPause

```
context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```